# ADF selectItem tag does not produce expected HTML

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm trying to produce a simple selection in ADF.  I tried something like this:

```
      <af:selectOneChoice label="#{bindings.items.label}" id="soc1"
                          value="#{bindings.items.inputValue}"
                          required="#{bindings.items.hints.mandatory}">
           <af:selectItem id="si3" value="L" label="Left"/>
           <af:selectItem id="si3" value="R" label="Right"/>
      </af:selectOneChoice>
```

According to the documentation for `af:selectItem`, this should produce HTML `<option>` tags with the same `label=` and `value=` contents as shown in the source.  However, that is not what happens.  The `value=` attributes are changed to "1", "2" (and so on), and there is a message in the log file about not being able to convert them to integers.  If I change the values to "34" and "52", just to see what happens, they are still changed to "1" and "2".

The documentation clearly says that the value= attribute specifies the value to be sent to the server, and makes no mention that it should be an integer, or that the supplied value will be replaced with a new value.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Or is this just the way it's supposed to work?

Here's the documentation:  http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/docs/tagdoc/af_selectItem.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the valuePassThru attribute of `<af:selectOneChoice>` to true. By default its set to false, which makes the values to be indices.

```
 <af:selectOneChoice label="#{bindings.items.label}" id="soc1"
                      value="#{bindings.items.inputValue}"
                      valuePassThru="true"
                      required="#{bindings.items.hints.mandatory}">
       <af:selectItem id="si3" value="L" label="Left"/>
       <af:selectItem id="si3" value="R" label="Right"/>
  </af:selectOneChoice>
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick.  Next time, I'll read the docs for the enclosing tags, too.  I didn't realize there was so much inherited behavior.

Comment: glad that you got it working. With ADF you got to read what those attributes do. At times the attributes themselves have lots of power packed in them :)